# Question on chemical equilibrium

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, stoichiometry, mole

8 moles of so2 and 4 moles of O2 are mixed in a closed vessel.the reaction proceeds at constant temperature. By the moment when equilibrium sets in,80% of the initial amount of so2 enters into the reaction. The equilibrium pressure would be?    My attempt: reaction will be 2so2+O2---->2so3. There will be 1.6mole of so2,0.8 mole of O2 remaining and 6.4 mole of so3 will be formed. Now how to find the equilibrium pressure?

Comment: Is 4 bigger than 3.2 ?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread, I have edited.

Comment: As the volume is not given you cannot, unless you a priori know the K expressed in equilibrium pressures, as the reaction Quotient is pressure dependent.

Comment: This question given to me had an option 2.17 and an option bearing 'can not be calculated' and clearly answer given to me was 2.17 atm. so I feel it is solvable.

Comment: So let have 1 mol of oxygen, at unknown temperature and volume. What is the pressure ? It is as asking for p from p=nRT/V, where you know neither T neither V.

Comment: That's why I am asking this question. It must be solvable somehow

Comment: Another option is accidentally missing data for the task. Or, you may express the relative pressure, you need not T nor V for it.

Comment: May be I don't know they meant standard condition?¿

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do by relative pressure?

Comment: Not that you may. You should now, unless you are very underprepared.

Comment: I know the method which we write by partial pressure raised to their stoichiometric coefficient which require total pressure as delta n which is (2-(2+1)) not zero . So we would require total pressure. Can you further explain?

Comment: **HINT** - Start with *"8 moles of so2 and 4 moles of O2 are mixed in a closed vessel."* The problem doesn't specify the volume of the container, so let's just assume that the total pressure of the gas is $p$. What is the partial pressure of $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ in the unreacted gases?

Comment: @MaxW I have tried. Why don't you write a answer.

Comment: @SMSheikh -- Sorry, I misread the problem.  I was thinking of calculating the equilibrium constant. User Poutnik's comment is correct. You need more information. Did you write the problem exactly as given?

Comment: @MaxW  you can check the book "Modern approach to chemical calculation: an introduction to the mole concept" by RC mukerjee,page number 835 ,question number 164, chapter : miscellaneous objective questions have this question and answer is clearly 2.17 atm.

Comment: @MaxW yes I am 100 % sure. I have written the ditto question.